# List<T> Serialization Throws Exception In WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF service and it contains it's interface, class definitions and some other object classes. It compiles fine, but when I run it I get:

```
Type 'sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

My `sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type` class is also has a attribute `[Serializable]`. But whatever I've done, i could not get it to succeed.

How can i accomplish setting this class into serializable? Is there way to implement this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web;

namespace sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.proxy.services.location.type
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IType" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IType
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Delete?id={id}")]
    CompositeType Select(Guid id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(CompositeType))]
    CompositeType List();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Add(sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type type);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Update(sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type type);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void Delete(Guid id);
}

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Type" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Type.svc or Type.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Type : IType
{
    public CompositeType Select(Guid id)
    {
        return new CompositeType().Select(id);
    }
    public CompositeType List()
    {
        return new CompositeType().List();
    }
    public void Add(sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type type)
    {
    }
    public void Update(sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type type)
    {
    }
    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public TypeColumns Columns { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public TypeData Data { get; set; }

    public CompositeType()
    {
        Columns = new TypeColumns();
        Data = new TypeData();
    }
    public CompositeType Select(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var composite = new CompositeType();

            var columns = ((HttpContext.Current.Session["PRINCIPAL"] as sarus.division.common.localization.data.principal.intelligence.Intelligence).Hubs["warehouse.cmms"].Hive["LOCATION-TYPE"] as sarus.division.common.localization.data.hive.drone.Drone).GetColumns();
            foreach (var column in columns) { composite.Columns.Add(column); }

            var data = new sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type().Select(id);

            composite.Data.Add(data);

            return composite;
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
    public CompositeType List()
    {
        try
        {
            var composite = new CompositeType();

            var columns = ((HttpContext.Current.Session["PRINCIPAL"] as sarus.division.common.localization.data.principal.intelligence.Intelligence).Hubs["warehouse.cmms"].Hive["LOCATION-TYPE"] as sarus.division.common.localization.data.hive.drone.Drone).GetColumns();
            foreach (var column in columns) { composite.Columns.Add(column); }

            var list = sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type.List();
            foreach (var data in list) { composite.Data.Add(data); }

            return composite;
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "GridViewColumn{0}List", ItemName = "GridViewColumn")]
public class TypeColumns : List<sarus.division.common.infrastructure.data.foundation.definitions.GridViewColumn>
{
    public TypeColumns()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public TypeColumns(sarus.division.common.infrastructure.data.foundation.definitions.GridViewColumn[] items)
        : base()
    {
        foreach (sarus.division.common.infrastructure.data.foundation.definitions.GridViewColumn item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Type{0}List", ItemName = "Type")]
public class TypeData : List<infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type>
{
    public TypeData()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public TypeData(infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type[] items)
        : base()
    {
        foreach (infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: here is 'sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type' class;

```
    using sarus.division.common.infrastructure.data.foundation.definitions;
    using sarus.division.common.infrastructure.data.logic.user;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Common;

    namespace sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type
    {
        public class Type : actual.Actual
        {
            public List<location.Location> Locations { get; set; }

            public Type(bool autoLoadDetails = false)
            {
            }

            public Type Select(Guid id)
            {
            }
            public List<Type> Select()
            {
            }
            public static List<Type> List()
            {
            }
            public void Save()
            {
            }

            public void Delete()
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right in your error message. `[Serializable]` may not work depending on the serialization code being used. Try marking your class and properties as it suggests. Also, anything that gets serialized needs to be marked, too, so you will need to the same to your `Location` class.

```
namespace sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Type : actual.Actual
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<location.Location> Locations { get; set; }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Type" in code, svc and config file together.
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Type.svc or Type.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Type : IType
{
   ....
}
```

I do not see a `[Serializable]` attribute here.  And based on your error:

> Type '**sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type**' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

This is the class it's complaining about.

Comment: why does Type : IType should have [Serializable] attribute? Should it?   The function List returns CompositeType object and CompositeType class has [Serializable] attribute. And for my other class (sarus.division.warehouse.cmms.infrastructure.data.logic.location.type.Type) has [Serializable] attribute. Here it is; `
    public class Type : actual.Actual
    {
        public List<location.Location> Locations { get; set; }

        public Type(bool autoLoadDetails = false)
        {
        }
        public static List<Type> List()
        {
        }
    }
}`

Comment: All classes that are going to be serialized need the [Serializable] attribute. Type is being serialized in CompositeType.TypeData. It requires the attribute.

Comment: @KadirAtesoglu Yes, I believe the problem is that the `Type` class is accepted as a parameter to your method, therefore it must be serialized to become a paramter, and deserialized into an instance for the method to consume.